# getting Geocoder to detect hardcoded ip in dev env and display data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-geocoder

Just installed Geocoder and trying to get it to show signs of life. I want a user to log in and have the profile landing page to show data on their ip. Since I'm in the dev environment, here is my attempt at a temporary solution:

```
class SessionsController 

  def create
    user = User.authenticate(params[:username_or_email], params[:password])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to profile_path, :notice => "Logged in!"
      @request = Rack::Request.new({'REMOTE_ADDR' => '107.128.188.218'})
      @location = @request.location
    #blah blah blah
  end
```

in the view:

```
<%= @location.data %>
```

the error I get is `undefined method 'data' for nil:NilClass`

in the intializers/geocoder.rb

```
Geocoder.configure(
  :timeout => 30
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning ivars `@request` and `@location` in the create action of your SessionsController, but the lifetime of these variables is just that request. After the controller action finishes, you are redirecting the client's browser to your `ProfilesController`, so you need to move those two assignments into `ProfilesController#show`, then it should work.

EDIT: Since you say you are using the `SessionsController` show action for the user's profile, moving those two statements to that action method should do the trick. :-)

Comment: I don't have a Profiles controller. I have Users and Sessions. Bad design?

Comment: Then where does `profile_path` map to? Maybe add your routes to your question?

Comment: Did you mean to say `user_path(user)` ? If so, then just replace `ProfilesController` with `UsersController` in my answer (which I will do if that's the case)

Comment: profile is `sessions#show`. profile is defined as logged in user's own profile. For other users it's `users#show`.

Comment: ultimately tracking by ip is only needed for a `current_user` to see Events that are within x miles from him.

Comment: I probably wouldn't use the `SessionsController` show action for a user's profile page - semantically the session resource is really a different thing than a user's profile. Might be more appropriate to actually create a `ProfilesController`, maybe even as a singular resource (`resource :profile, only: [:show]` in your `routes.rb`), then you could keep the `redirect_to profile_path` and just access the user's info with `current_user` in `ProfilesController#show`.

Comment: Alternatively, from your most recent comment it sounds like what you may actually be after is more of a dashboard, and having a singular resource for dashboard backed by `DashboardsController` is a fairly common pattern...

Comment: I moved the geocoder stuff under the `show` action in the same controller and that solved the problem. If you want to add that somewhere in your answer, I'll select it as correct. I will look into your other suggestions. Thank you!